# What is the correct code for country_select when I use simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Without simple_form, my code for country_select will be:

```
<%= f.label :country %>
<%= f.country_select :country, include_blank: true %>
```

But with simple_form gem installed, will this be the code?:

```
<%= f.input :country %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Simple Form will pick up the string "country" in the attribute name, and automatically apply country_select underneath, provided you include the country_select gem in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'country_select'
```

You can force the mapping, if necessary with:

```
<%= f.input :field_name, as: :country %>
```